# Can't copy a fixed-size byte array from a struct to another array in a struct in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

Using the `NetworkInfo2SecurityParameter` function I am trying to copy the fixed-size buffer `unkRandom` from from `LdnNetworkInfo` struct held in `NetworkInfo` struct to the `SecurityParameter` struct's buffer.

Basically I am making a method to convert these two types, and I want to copy these two arrays to another. This code features all structs relevant.

The error is happening at the `Buffer.MemoryCopy()` function. The error is "You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the 'fixed' statement"

```
unsafe void NetworkInfo2SecurityParameter(NetworkInfo info, out SecurityParameter output)
{
    output = new SecurityParameter();
    output.sessionId = info.networkId.sessionId;
    Buffer.MemoryCopy(output.unkRandom, info.ldn.unkRandom, 16, 16);
}

struct SecurityParameter {
    public unsafe fixed byte unkRandom[16];// = new byte[16];
    public SessionId sessionId;
};

struct NetworkInfo : /sf::/LargeData {
    public NetworkId networkId;
    public CommonNetworkInfo common;
    public LdnNetworkInfo ldn;
};

struct LdnNetworkInfo {
    public unsafe fixed byte unkRandom[16];// = new byte[16];
    public ushort securityMode;
    public byte stationAcceptPolicy;
    public unsafe fixed byte _unk1[3];// = new byte[3];
    public byte nodeCountMax;
    public byte nodeCount;
    //TODO non primitive array,,
    private unsafe fixed byte _nodes[sizeof(NodeInfo)*NodeCountMax]; //Needs to be fixed array, and needs to be casted to NodeInfo span, so thats why its size is this
    public unsafe fixed Span<NodeInfo> nodes => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, NodeInfo>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref _nodes[0], 128));
    public ushort _unk2;
    public ushort advertiseDataSize;
    public unsafe fixed byte advertiseData[AdvertiseDataSizeMax];// = new byte[AdvertiseDataSizeMax];
    public unsafe fixed byte _unk3[148];// = new byte[148];
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the 'fixed' statement

Comment: Well, the obvious question is, have you tried using the `fixed` statement?

Comment: If the array is just 16 bytes, could you take a pointer to the array, cast it to a int64 pointer and copy it in two 64-bit chunks?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Where?

Comment: @JonasH Interesting solution, may use it as a last resort though

Comment: Well seems I fixed it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct` is assignable, like any primitive. Undoubtedly faster than `Buffer.MemoryCopy()` would be:

```
public unsafe struct FixedSizeBufferWrapper
{
    public unsafe fixed byte unkRandom[16];
}

unsafe 
{
    fixed (byte* firstStruct = somewhere.securityParameter, otherStruct = somewhereElse.ldnNetworkInfo )
    {
        //one assignment blits all contents
        *((FixedSizeBufferWrapper*)firstStruct.unkRandom) =
        *((FixedSizeBufferWrapper*)otherStruct.unkRandom);
    }
}
```

We cast buffers in each of your original structs to the wrapper pointer type and dereference each pointer SO THAT we can assign one to the other; assigning `fixed` buffers directly is not possible.

We have to cast outside the `fixed` statement because (at least in my version of C#) we aren't allowed to  cast inside `fixed(...)` and we cannot assign anything other than a primitive type (usually `byte[]`) as the buffer type. The wrapper struct exists purely for this casting / assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this approach: I created a new variable called ret, which I did copy the data to, and then I assigned ret to output.

```
unsafe void NetworkInfo2SecurityParameter(NetworkInfo info, out SecurityParameter output)
        {
            var ret = new SecurityParameter();
            output.sessionId = info.networkId.sessionId;
            Buffer.MemoryCopy(ret.unkRandom, info.ldn.unkRandom, 16, 16);
            output = ret;
        }
```